# How can I do to get a json from an url using reactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I would like to get data from a json using an url with reactJS but it does not work.
The url where I want to get data is the following : [url](https://soundcloud.com/oembed?url=http%3A//soundcloud.com/forss/flickermood&format=json)

Here is my code :

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import axios from "axios";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { member: [] };
  }

  memberList(list) {
    const memberList = list.map((member, index) => {
      return (
        <li>
          {member.name} {member.age}
        </li>
      );
    });

    return <ul>{memberList}</ul>;
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.member);
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.getJson}>Get json</button>
        {this.memberList(this.state.member)}
      </div>
    );
  }

  getJson = () => {
    const url =
      "https://soundcloud.com/oembed?url=http%3A//soundcloud.com/forss/flickermood&format=json";

    axios.get(url).then((res) => {
      // console.log(res.data);
      this.setState(res.data);
    });
  };
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

and the project is there : [my project](https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-chandrasekhar-6l70g?file=/src/index.js)

Thank you for your help !

Comment: What "doesn't work" about it?  How specifically is this failing?

Comment: But, what happens? Do you get an error?

Comment: fetch() API might be easier than axios https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: It works for me on CodeSandbox

Comment: I mean if I try a console.log I have nothing

Comment: I guess that you should use the setState differently: `this.setState({ member: [res.data] });`.
And in memberList have something like `{member.author_name} {member.title}`